# How to dynamically load external angular 2 module (like served from an external module.bundle.js)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-modules

I can dynamically load local modules as someone else did in the [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/khdS8xFkvqe7ZIsz0kc7?p=preview). But how do I load an external module, lets say from a separate bundle js served by another service. In the example plunker, src/app.ts has:

```
  constructor(private viewref: ViewContainerRef,
      private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
      private loader: SystemJsNgModuleLoader,
      private compiler: Compiler){
        this.module = new ModuleNode();
        //can I make this a non-local script reference somehow?
        //like to http://example.net/external.module.bundle.js
        this.module.modulePath = "src/dynamic.module#DynamicModule";
        this.module.componentName = "TestComponent";
      }
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT:** To clarify, the scenario is that a group of microservices (built, deployed, etc. independently) are making a spa. So my microservice wants to dynamically load a component/ module from a bundle.js served by another microservice. This is why I don't have the module/ bundle at compile time. The only contract between the two microservices is the url to the bundle file. If they update the component/ module, a hard refresh should reflect the changes without a re-deployment of my microservice.

Comment: You can't load modules individually from another bundle because you are loading the entire bundle. Why not map the module to your SystemJS config?

Comment: @PaulJeromeBordallo Edited the question to more clearly explain the use case. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Are you still using the version 2 of angular? Still interested in a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer which come into my mind is `angular-architects/module-federation` but I'm pretty sure it won't work with Angular v2. The only solution I see for such an outadated version of Angular is to use Webpack to handle you projects buildings and use its module federation feature.