# Get and load a remote component/module in an angular 4.4 app

Tags: angular, plugins, systemjs

Here is what i'm trying de achieve : 
I want to create an app using "plugins", by plugins I mean :

Another angular component/module that could be deployed on a remote host and displayed in my app.

Looks like I can't do such thing with webpack directly and that I should use SystemJs to dynamically load a module.

Any advice would be welcome to use SystemJs and Webpack (ng cli), examples of how to call remote module and load them.

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes but not using systemjs at all

Comment: Am trying to accomplish the same thing, would you be kind and post an answer or provide the steps that worked for you? thanks.

Comment: I need to make a github project, once I have few minutes but the idea is : create your plugin as an angular app, bundle it as an UMD, in your main app do a simple get to retrieve the plugin bundle and use "classic" dynamic component use as describe on angular website

Comment: what do you mean by a simple get? a simple HTTP get request? how do you parse the module then with its dependencies? I really appreciate your help as am not able to make it work.

Comment: have a look at this repo, this will help : https://github.com/Toxicable/module-loading

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149016/load-new-modules-dynamically-in-run-time-with-angular-cli-angular-5/50395048#50395048

Comment: @Seb How did you solve it in the end, without using SystemJS ?

Comment: too long time to remember sry

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to add systemjs to your angular-cli and use it to load a module. Then you can use `componentFactoryResolver` to resolve the components you need in the module. To add `systemjs` to your project install it:

```
npm i systemjs
```

and the following into `angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"
],
```

Also add a link to scripts.js in the page :

This will load systemjs and it will available as a global object. You can then use it like this:

```
declare var SystemJS;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    SystemJS.load(...);
  }
```

For details how to use SystemJS to load a module see [How to load dynamic external components into Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506470/2545680) answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll give it a try today ! just one more question, should the remote module be packaged in a specific way ?

Comment: ok Great, when trying to use SystemJs in a component, it looks like i can't get access to it, weird. is there anything I should do for angualr to take account of the new dependency ?

Comment: it should be available as a global variable, not a dependency, see my example above

Comment: Yes my mistake, i didn't notice the declare var SystemJS;
Just an exported class with applied decorator, shouldn't I expose a builded module from my remote server ?

Comment: @Seb, what do you mean `builded module`? aot compiled?

Comment: yes aot compiled, actually it's kind of hard for me to understand how to make my module available on a webserver and what url I should hit to retrieve it.

Comment: how do you build it?

Comment: ng build --prod, so using aot compilation

Comment: what I mean is should I try to get http://xxx/vendor.bundle.js or http://xxxx/main.bundle.js or http://xxx/inline.bundle.js

Comment: When getting the vendor.bundle.js i get : 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js detected as amd but didn't execute correctly

Comment: OK, I'll try later, when I have time

Comment: I start to think it's impossible, I can get an umd module remotly. This module use @angular/common so SystemJS when it loads the module tries to get localhost:8080/xx/@angular/common. looks like SystemJS does not know about the context its running into, any idea ?

Comment: it's certainly doable, but requires understanding for how webpack bundles modules together. I haven't had time to look at it yet.

Comment: Maybe I need to use SystemJS in my main app as well ?

Comment: @Seb, do you maybe want to setup a paid session on codementor.io?

Comment: @Seb, if it's around 15 minutes I think I can make for free. I just need a record on codementor.io. Let me explore this option

Comment: did you published the result? @AngularInDepth.com

Comment: @user3757628, no, didn't have time

Comment: @user3757628, I didn't have time to implement anything, there's nothing to share

Answer (score 2):

I have realized getting and loading remote component based on Angular 4. Feel free to check my github project:https://github.com/dianadujing/dynamic-remote-component-loader

Comment: Thanks for the sample! Would this work flawlessly with AOT? Maybe the JIT compiler has to be manually created and provided?

Comment: @LppEdd Actually, that's where I was stuck. Finally, I chose to upgrade my Angular version to 6.

Comment: Isn't it the same? I mean, when using AOT the JIT compiler gets stripped away from the page