# Angular5: Dynamic component loading - StaticInjector error with @angular/core dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am migrating an electron application from AngularJS to Angular5 and I am facing issues in a part where I need to load an arbitrary module with its components and render the main component to the view dynamically (it's an addon system).
In my application, an addon is an angular5 module containing a component which is rendered in my angular5 application.

I load dynamically the component like this:

```js
@ViewChild("view", { read: ViewContainerRef })
view: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
  // ...
  private compiler: Compiler,
  private injector: Injector,
  private moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any>
) {}
```

then,

```js
const addonModule = addonObject.getModule();
this.compiler
  .compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(addonModule)
  .then(factories => {
    const factory = factories.componentFactories.find(
      componentFactory =>
        addonObject.getViewComponent().name ==
        componentFactory.componentType.name
    );
    if (factory) {
      const cmpRef = factory.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);
      cmpRef.instance.config = {
        from: "afd@test.com",
        apikey: "dsfkjd"
      };
      this.view.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
    }
  });
```

it works great but when I add Material Component in the template, it fails at `factory.create()` with this error:

template:

```html
<div>
    <button mat-button>test</button>
</div>
```

error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[Renderer2]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Renderer2]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer2!
```

or

template:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex>
    test
</div>
```

error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[MediaMonitor]: 
  StaticInjectorError[MediaMonitor]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MediaMonitor!
```

The Material modules seems well imported in my addon module else if it's not loaded I have different behaviors: it ignores directives (e.g. `<button mat-button></button>` is just a `<button></button>` without material effect and without errors) and material component throw errors (e.g. `<mat-card>test<mat-card>` throws `Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-card' is not a known element...`)

I have tried to bundle the dynamic module in many different ways: tsc / ngc / ng-packagr / webpack.

The bundle is working when I import it normally (static) in the NgModule of another app built with ng-cli.

Does someone know how to render dynamically a component which has material component/directive used in the template like fxFlex / mat-button / mat-card ?

EDIT: I have made a reproduction of the bug with SystemJS here: https://github.com/thyb/repro-dynamic-loading

Angular: 5.0.2

Angular Material: 5.0.0-rc1

Comment: Can you setup reproduction?

Comment: @yurzui yes, https://github.com/thyb/repro-dynamic-loading

Comment: Thanks for reproduction. The problem you have is connected with the fact that your application loads two `core.umd.js` files. When angular resolves dependencies it stores ElementRef class as key. And then uses this key. Since you have two definitions of ElementRef angular can't solve provider. http://take.ms/Vq5F0

Comment: Systemjs loads `core.umd.js` as `file:///...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! 2 things I'm not understanding is :
- Why the first example works while it is using Angular Core to define the module / component ?
- How can I use the same Angular Core object using SystemJS than the one used in the "main-app" ?

Comment: As I'm using it in an Electron application, I haven't find another way than file:/// to load my modules

Comment: The first example works because there is no ElemenetRef dependency. Try to add `private elRef: ElementRef` here in constructor https://github.com/thyb/repro-dynamic-loading/blob/master/addon/src/core/src/components/addon-view/addon-view.component.ts#L8 Second example uses it through `mat-button` component https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/button/button.ts#L138

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. So, my last question is, how to make the injector working for @angular/* modules in my addons? :)

Comment: That's good question)

Comment: I've succeeded to share @angular/* modules using `window` to store modules globally. It's not elegant but it has the merit to work... to import angular core in my addon I use `const NgModule = window.angular.core.NgModule` instead of the traditional `import {NgModule} from "@angular/core"` and in my index.html, I import in window all modules that needs to be shared (`@angular/core`, `@angular/common` etc..). I've also read/watch about Angular Elements which seems perfect for this use case: https://youtu.be/ljsOPm4MMEo?t=13m20s.

Answer (score 2):

As @yurzui explained in comments, the @angular/* dependencies were loaded twice. As a workaround, the only way I found to make it work is by using `window` to share the @angular objects between the application and the addons (`@angular/core`, `@angular/common`, `@angular/material`).

in my application index.html:

```
window.angular = {
    core: require("@angular/core"),
    common: require("@angular/common"),
    material: require("@angular/material"),
    ...
}
```

and in my addons:

```
const NgModule = (window as any).angular.core.NgModule;
const CommonModule = (window as any).angular.common.CommonModule;
const MatButtonModule = (window as any).angular.material.MatButtonModule;
...
```

It's not really elegant (bye bye tree shaking) but at least it works... If someone has a simpler solution, I take it :)

I came across a discussion on Gitter about [@angular/element](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/labs/elements) which seems promising as it creates standalone/self contained web component which could be injected dynamically without the issues I encountered - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljsOPm4MMEo&feature=youtu.be&t=13m20s. This is a lab project so not available in the current releases but there is already some work on it: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19469