# How do i import a remote component in angular 5 or 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, components, angular6

This project contains a working example and works great

https://github.com/dianadujing/dynamic-remote-component-loader

I'm trying to repurpose this code for my own project:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hamoom/afe499b60b55f3af8fd31eb04ca8cadf/raw/cf71ea940b54691085e9b9267ee62a52a167d927/app.module.ts';
console.log(System.import(url));

const importer = (url:any) => Observable.fromPromise(System.import(url));
console.log('importer:', importer);
importer(url)
  .subscribe((modules) => {
    console.log('modules:', modules, modules['AppModule']);
    this.cfr = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(modules['AppModule']);
    console.log(this.cfr,',', this.cfr.componentFactories[0]);
    this.putStuffHere.createComponent(this.cfr.componentFactories[0], 0);
  });
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find
>   module
>   'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hamoom/afe499b60b55f3af8fd31eb04ca8cadf/raw/cf71ea940b54691085e9b9267ee62a52a167d927/app.module.ts'.

also:

> /src/app/upsell/upsell.component.ts
>       35:20-38 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

i have tried using this too:

```
import(url).then(module => {
    console.log(module)               
  }
);
```

i still get this missing module error.  How can I grab this remote component?  this code only seems to work for components on the same file system now.

I managed to get this working using a component on my file system

```
  import('./meh.component').then(module => {
      console.log(module)
      this.cfr = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(module['AppModule']);
      this.footer.createComponent(this.cfr.componentFactories[0], 0);
    }
  );
```

if I change the parameter inside import to my remote script its unable to reach it..

Comment: Are you using `SystemJs`? `System.import(url)` is for `SystemJs`

Comment: i have "systemjs": "^0.21.3", in my package.json file and I've run npm install.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: If you have it and declare it globally it should work, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506470/6736888 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328636/6736888

Comment: i have "declare var System:any;" on the top of my file. is there a difference between System and SystemJs?

Comment: Not entirely sure, I think it should be `SystemJS` based on the src https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/dist/system.src.js#L2010